Range Closed and Nonempty Intersection of approximate point spectrum and residual spectrum
I am trying to disprove the statement in $\textrm{(a)(ii)}$.

so I need to find a bounded linear operator $A$ with $\operatorname{Im}A$ closed and $\sigma_{ap}(A)\cap\sigma_r(A)\ne\varnothing.$
My attempt:
Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator with $\operatorname{Im}A$ closed and $\sigma_{ap}(A)\cap\sigma_r(A)\ne\varnothing.$
$A$ can't be a finite rank operator (If $\dim\operatorname{Im}A<\infty,$ then $σ_{ap}(A) = σ_p(A)$.)
Take $X=\ell^{2}$. Define$$A(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)=(0, a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\ldots)$$where $(a_n)$ is a sequence converging to $0$.
Then $\sigma(A)=\sigma_{ap}(A)=\sigma_r(A)=\{0\}$. But this example doesn't satisfy $\operatorname{Im}A$ is closed.

Let $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,\frac{x_1}1,\frac{x_2}2,\dots)$
then $T$ is compact such that

$\overline{\operatorname{Im}(T)}\ne\ell^2$ so that $0\in\sigma_c$
injective, so $\lambda=0\notin\sigma_p$
$\lambda=0\in\sigma_{ap}$ because: $\frac{\|Te_j\|}{\|e_j\|}=\frac1j\to0$
and: $\lambda\notin\sigma_{ap}\iff\exists\delta>0:\|(T-\lambda)x\|\ge\delta\|x\|$

Take $S=I+T$, image of $S$ closed (since $T$ is compact) and $\lambda=1$.
